# Integral of 1/f(z) over a unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

[image]
My lecturer has given solutions to this problem but I don't understand them.

Below is what she wrote

[image]

[image]

My issue is with the second part of the proof. I bounded 
(1/f(z) - 1/(f(z0)(z-z0)) = phi(z)/(f'(z)f(z)).
But from this point now I don't understand what she did after this point to achieve the result.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the residue of $1/f(z)$ at $z=z_0$ is $1/f'(z_0)$.

In more detail, $f$ is nonzero except at $z=z_0$ so the only
singularity of $f$ inside the circle is at $z_0$. So the integral
is $2\pi i$ times the residue of $1/f(z)$ at $z=z_0$. By the conditions
given, $f(z)$ has Taylor series
$$f(z)=f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+a_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots$$
and so
$$\frac1{f'(z)}=\frac1{f'(z_0)}\frac1{z-z_0}+b_0+b_1(z-z_0)^2+\cdots
$$
so the residue is $1/f'(z_0)$

Answer (score 0):

There are two ideas in the proof.

The first is that if $g$ is analytic on $B(z_0,2) \setminus \{z_0\}$ then using Cauchy's integral theorem we can show that
for any $\delta>0$ (and less than $2$), we have
$\int_{|z-z_0|=1} g(z) dz = \int_{|z-z_0|=\delta} g(z) dz$. Hence we
can choose our circle as small as we want.

The second is that since $f(z) = f'(z_0) (z-z_0)+ \phi(z)(z-z_0)$ (where $\phi(z) \to 0$ as $z \to z_0$), we would like if
${1 \over f(z)} \approx {1 \over f'(z_0) (z-z_0)}$ since we know how to compute the latter.

Note that since $\phi(z) \to 0$ we can find a $\delta>0$ such that
for $|z-z_0| \le \delta$ we have $|f(z)| \ge { 1\over 2}|f'(z_0)| |z-z_0|$.

Note that $|{1 \over a} - {1 \over b}| \le {|a-b| \over |ab|}$ for $a,b \neq 0$.

Hence $|{1 \over f(z)} - {1 \over f'(z_0) (z-z_0)}| \le {|\phi(z)(z-z_0) | \over |f(z) f'(z_0)(z-z_0)| } = {|\phi(z) | \over |f(z) f'(z_0)| } \le {2|\phi(z) | \over |f'(z_0)|^2|z-z_0| }$ as long as $0< |z-z_0| \le \delta$.

Now choose $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta' \le \delta$ such that if
$0<|z-z_0| \le \delta'$ then $|\phi(z) | < \epsilon$, which gives
$|{1 \over f(z)} - {1 \over f'(z_0) (z-z_0)}| < {2 \epsilon  \over |f'(z_0)|^2|z-z_0| } $.

Now integrate around the circle $|z-z_0| = \delta'$ to get
\begin{eqnarray}
|\int_{|z-z_0| = \delta'}({1 \over f(z)} - {1 \over f'(z_0) (z-z_0)}) dz| &\le&  \int_{|z-z_0| = \delta'}|{1 \over f(z)} - {1 \over f'(z_0) (z-z_0)}| |dz| \\
&<& \int_{|z-z_0| = \delta'} {2 \epsilon  \over |f'(z_0)|^2|z-z_0| } |dz| \\
&=& {4 \pi \epsilon  \over |f'(z_0)|^2 }
\end{eqnarray}
Hence we have
$\int_{|z-z_0| = 1}{1 \over f(z)} dz = \int_{|z-z_0| = 1} {1 \over f'(z_0) (z-z_0)}dz = {2 \pi i \over f'(z_0)}$.

Comment: Why should $|f(z)| \geq \frac{1}{2}|f‘(z_0)||z–z_0| $??? That would mean that $|\phi(z)||z–z_0| $ makes up a relatively big part of f(z) even though it should become smaller while the linear part makes up a growing part,

Comment: Choose $\delta>0$ small enough so that  for $|z-z_0| < \delta$ then $|\phi(z)| \le {1 \over 2} |f'(z_0)|$.

Comment: How do you get this. Could you spell that out? The only thing I get is:$ |f(z)| \leq (|fˋ(z_0)| + \frac{1}{2} |fˋ(z_0)|)|z–z_0| $!

Comment: You know that $\phi(z) \to 0$ as $z \to z_0$. And $|f(z)| \ge (|f'(z_0)|-|\phi(z))) |z-z_0|$.

Comment: Yes which means that the linearisation of f(z) should should get closer and closer to f(z). This inequality is doing the opposite! Or what am I completely misunderstanding? If I’m wrong could you be so kind to spell it out explicitly?    Why should your last inequality be true?

Comment: If $a=b+c$ then $|a|\ge |b|-|c|$. This is just the triangle inequality.

Comment: Even if it’s true, I don’t see it…

Comment: You need to so some work. $b=a-c$ so $|b| = |a-c| \le |a| + |c|$. Now move the $|c|$ to the other side.

Comment: I got it know thanks!!!